# Pandas categorical data conversion

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
df1 = DataFrame({'Site Name' : pd.Categorical(list('EENEESENNENNENNWNWSSESSESSWSWVRBWWNWWSW'),categories=['E','ENE','ESE','N','NE','NNE','NNW','NW','S','SE','SSE','SSW','SW','VRB','W','WNW','WSW']), 'B' : numpy.arange(20) })
```

This is my code to convert categorical data, i keep getting an error like this

"ValueError: arrays must all be same length"

Please help me out

Comment: What are you expecting here? you 'Site Name' column has 39 entries and your next column 20, if you changed to `arange(39)` then it runs

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because 'Site Name' is a categorical with 39 entries whilst your 'B' column has 20 entries, if you changed it to match the length (`np.arange(39)`)then it works fine:

```
In [5]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Site Name' : pd.Categorical(list('EENEESENNENNENNWNWSSESSESSWSWVRBWWNWWSW'),categories=['E','ENE','ESE','N','NE','NNE','NNW','NW','S','SE','SSE','SSW','SW','VRB','W','WNW','WSW']), 'B' : np.arange(39) })
df1

Out[5]:
     B Site Name
0    0         E
1    1         E
2    2         N
3    3         E
4    4         E
5    5         S
6    6         E
7    7         N
8    8         N
9    9         E
10  10         N
11  11         N
12  12         E
13  13         N
14  14         N
15  15         W
16  16         N
17  17         W
18  18         S
19  19         S
20  20         E
21  21         S
22  22         S
23  23         E
24  24         S
25  25         S
26  26         W
27  27         S
28  28         W
29  29       NaN
30  30       NaN
31  31       NaN
32  32         W
33  33         W
34  34         N
35  35         W
36  36         W
37  37         S
38  38         W
```

The DataFrame ctor requires that when passing a dict as the data param all values must be array-like and the same length